# Difference between slump/stoop/slouch?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What’s the difference between these three words as far as postures are concerned?

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples [on a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not.

Answer (score 1):

**Slump** and **slouch** are synonyms both meaning to sit or stand lazily but **stoop** means to completely bend as if you are picking something up from the ground.